# VB.net added listbox item

Tags: vb.net, listbox

Is there a sub where you can put in a code when a listbox item is added?

( example )

```
Private Sub listboxitemadded(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles listbox1.listboxitemadded

      my code...

End Sub
```

Comment: You may need to catch an event from the items container that the listBox uses to store items. I don't see an event like you're asking for in the Control's documentation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would add all you LixtBox items into a generic [BindingList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx). Then bind that list to your ListBox.

The BindingList has an event call 'AddingNew' that you can hook into to know when items have been added to the list.

Comment: Thank you i think i can do that :P